# How to remove a keychain in xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu

A **keychain** has been installed for the **remmina** application. Some time later, the password was forgotten. How do I delete this **keychain** or reset my password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the directory `~/.local/share/keyrings` or find the specific file in that directory and delete it. Also note that you don't have to setup a keyring when asked you can simply cancel the dialog and not use a keyring if desired.